# Is there something similar to PostSharp logging, but for Java?

Tags: library, java, automation, logs

Using PostSharp, one can add and customize logging to an existing .NET project. For example you can log the entry and exit of every method or all methods except getters and setters, along with arguments and return values. There is almost no modification in the source code of the project required, just have to add a few imports and create a new file for our logging configuration.

https://www.postsharp.net/logging (There is a short video here as well, explaining what Postsharp logging does briefly)

I am looking for something similar which would work for Java projects. I know something similar can be achieved using Aspect4j or Java-assist, but that still requires a significant amount of source code modification (Adding advice over all the methods I want to log). Are there any better options?

Comment: I have not tried it but [BTrace](https://github.com/btraceio/btrace) seems to allow Java function tracing/logging (by manipulating the class byte code at run-time). And for Java on Android (unfortunately not for J2SE) [frida-trace](https://frida.re/docs/frida-trace/) should be suitable.